# SearchView custom font in android

Tags: android, fonts, searchview, android-typeface

I have been trying to set custom font to the `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` query hint and the text entered in the View.I did try setting the font dynamically from the *assests* to the searchView by creating a TypeFace object, but the problem occurs that **"SearchView doesn't contain a setTypeface(Typeface tf) method."** I did try for a custom SearchView class but couldn't find one.

```
 private void setFont(String font1, String font2, String font3)
 {
        Typeface tf = null;

        tf = UiUtil.changeFont(MainActivity.this, font1);
        btn1.setTypeface(tf);

        tf = UiUtil.changeFont(MainActivity.this, font2);
        btn2.setTypeface(tf);

        tf = UiUtil.changeFont(MainActivity.this, font3);
        btn3.setTypeface(tf);

         tf = UiUtil.changeFont(MainActivity.this, font3);
        // no set typeface method..

    }
```

Comment: Try this `searchView.setQueryHint(Html.fromHtml("<font face = tf>" + getResources().getString(R.string.search_hint) + "</font>"));
`

Comment: @Apurva let me check and let you know

Comment: @Apurva Nope this isn't working..

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The workaround here is to first get the searchView's textView and then change the typeface for the textView instead:

```
 TextView searchText = (TextView)
 searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
 Typeface myCustomFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/myFont.ttf");
 searchText.setTypeface(myCustomFont);
```

Or, if you're not using appcompatv7:

```
 int id = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
 TextView searchText = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(id);
```

then set the typeface as usual.

Comment: While I assume this works, you're assuming implementation details of the SearchView class.  These could change at any time, it isn't a safe assumption.

Comment: For androidX, the ID to search for is androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text

Comment: @amitav13 I get a null `TextView` in AndroidX if I use `androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text` as ID. However, the second method that uses `getIdentifier()` works for me exactly as it is suggested. I don't have to change `android:id/search_src_text` to `androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text`. Any ideas why `androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text` ain't working?

Answer (score 5):

To change the font family in searchview programmatically from xml font folder:

```
Typeface tf = ResourcesCompat.getFont(dis,R.font.montserrat_regular);
TextView searchText = (TextView)search_view.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
searchText.setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 4):

For Kotlin and Androidx

```
val face: Typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context?.assets, "font.otf")
val searchText = searchView.findViewById<View>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text) as TextView
searchText.typeface = face
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all the previous answers, I found my best solution witch I hope that you find it the cleanest answer, too.

This is working for **SearchView** class inside the package **android.widget**

First, create an extension like below:

```
import android.graphics.Typeface
import android.widget.SearchView
import android.widget.TextView

fun SearchView.setTypeFace(typeface: Typeface?) {
    val id = context.resources.getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null)
    val searchText = searchView.findViewById(id) as TextView
    searchText.typeface = typeface
}
```

Then use this extension wherever you like:

```
val typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(requireContext(), R.font.sans)
searchView.setTypeFace(typeface)
```

You may want to get typeface from assets or other ways. but the rest is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone looking to implement the same in xml

Try the solution mentioned this answer able to customise
{textSize, fontFamily, textColor, hideBottomLine} in SearchView - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73997430/3020859

[image]