# How to remove bottom line in android SearchView component?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, searchview

How to remove bottom line in android SearchView component? Like in this image:

[image]

Comment: you can refer to this link. It might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842921/how-to-remove-white-underline-in-a-searchview-widget-in-toolbar-android

Comment: Thanks, helped me for 100%

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove white underline in a SearchView widget in Toolbar Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842921/how-to-remove-white-underline-in-a-searchview-widget-in-toolbar-android)

Comment: I am glad I was able to help you :-) cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you get a reference to your `SearchView`; This will work:

```
val backgroundView = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate) as View
backgroundView.background = null
```

Comment: If I want to have custom background and also don't want that underline, your answer won't work...

Answer (score 29):

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
  app:queryBackground="@null"
  ...
/>
```

Setting this to @null in your XML will remove the colored bar.

Answer (score 5):

If you using the android namespace in your `SearchView` xml, the best way to remove the bottom line is:

`android:queryBackground="@null"`

Answer (score 2):

In layout.xml

```
<SearchView
    android:theme="@style/AppSearchView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corner_rect"
    android:queryBackground="@null"
    android:queryHint="Search here..."
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false" />
```

style.xml

```
 <style name="AppSearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/app_font</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: `app:queryBackground="@color/your_color"` and `android:background="@color/your_color"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `background="@null"` in xml in search view.

Answer (score 0):

Just write it in xml:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
   android:id="@+id/searchView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:queryBackground="@null"
   ... />
```

Worked for me